# how to calculate the number of matches of files which have different values in php

Tags: php, arrays, count, compare

For a multiple choice exam, i store the data in `.txt` files.

I have 8 `.txt` files in which stored 2 or more numbers. The name of the txt files are `1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ...`

The first number in each txt file is ALWAYS the correct answer. I want to compare this first number with the last number of that txt file.

```
foreach($all_files as $file) {
    $each_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $choosen_answer = substr($each_file, -1); // last number is the number user has choosen
    $correct_answer = substr($each_file, 0,1); // first number is the correct answer

    // output the answers
    echo '<span class="choosen_answer">'.$choosen_answer.'</span>'; 
    echo '<span class="correct_answer">'.$correct_answer.'</span>';

    $wrong = 0;
    if($choosen_answer != $correct_answer) { // compare the 2 values
        $wrong++;
        echo '<span class="wrong text-danger">Wrong</span>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<span class="correct text-success">Correct</span>';
    }

}
echo count($wrong); // this should give me the number of wrong answers, but it does not...
```

I want to calculate the number of wrong answers and i tried `count($wrong);` for this but it does not give me the number of wrong answers.

So what i need: if `3` of the `8` questions are wrong answered, it should give me the number `3`

Each txt file looks like this:

```
02 // 0 is the correct answer, 2 is the answer from the user. I compare 0 with 2. So wrong answer
```

or

```
14 // 1 is the correct answer. 4 is the answer of the user. I compare 1 with 4. So wrong answer
```

or

```
22 // 2 is the correct answer. 2 is also the answer of the user. So correct answer
```

Comment: `count()` is counting an array members. just do `echo $wrong;` instead.

Comment: `echo $wrong;` produces `0`. ( It should be `3`)

Comment: Please edit the question to include some examples of what the text files contains, expected result from those and what result you're currently getting.

Comment: @john, then your `if` block is wrong and `$wrong` didn't increment. did you try to debug (print) both `$choosen_answer` and `$correct_answer` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wrong = 0;` is in the foreach loop! so after every iteration, it makes it 0 again.

Your code should look like:

```
$wrong = 0;
foreach($all_files as $file) {
    $each_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $choosen_answer = substr($each_file, -1); // last number is the number user has choosen
    $correct_answer = substr($each_file, 0,1); // first number is the correct answer

    // output the answers
    echo '<span class="choosen_answer">'.$choosen_answer.'</span>'; 
    echo '<span class="correct_answer">'.$correct_answer.'</span>';

    if($choosen_answer != $correct_answer) { // compare the 2 values
        $wrong++;
        echo '<span class="wrong text-danger">Wrong</span>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<span class="correct text-success">Correct</span>';
    }

}
echo $wrong;
```